# dotenv in Apollo-Client doesn't works

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, dotenv

I create a file .env with the URLs, and I try to set them in the file apollo.js but i doesn't work.
When I write the url directly to the apollo.js file it works but when I link it to the .env file it doesn't work.
I have an error: "process is not defined". I write in the file apollo.js `require('dotenv').config()`
and I have same error.

.ENV

```
REACT_APP_URL = https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/
REACT_APP_LOCAL = http://localhost:4000/
```

APOLLO.JS

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const { REACT_APP_URL, REACT_APP_LOCAL } = process.env

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri:REACT_APP_LOCAL,
  fetch
})
```

Comment: make sure your `.env` file is in the root folder.

Comment: Yes, the .env is in the root folder